# complex properties with moq

Tags: prism, moq

I have something like:

```
UserControl view = _regionManager.Regions[Constants.FormDisplayerRegion].Views.FirstOrDefault() as UserControl;
```

I've mocked the region manager. Regions is a IRegionCollection, View is a IViewCollection.

What is the best way of dealing with this sort of thing.

1. Do I need to create mocks for Regions  and Views?
2. Or would I be better off skipping moq and creating my own stub?

Comment: That really depends on what you are trying to test. Presumably you've mocked the RegionManager because it is a dependency of something else you are testing. Its hard to make any sensible comments without the full picture.

Comment: The system under test needs to remove the existing view and navigate to a new one dependent on conditions. The question is basically how do I get the view. I guess I'm asking because this just seems awkward. Presently I stub my own regionManager, but it entails a fair bit of code and I suspect there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

With the very little information you've provided, it is hard to give a sensible response. From your description though, I'd say you just need to Setup your region manager mock so it returns a collection of views. The views collection can be faked.